# Proper formula for Debye field

Tags: electric-fields, plasma-physics

What is the proper formula for Debye field that accounts for not only electrons, but also for other charged particles that may be present in plasma? Information about it in the web is scarce and in the books it is only mentioned along side Debye length/radius that only accounts for electrons.

Comment: Do you have access to the following:  https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5091949

Answer (score 0):

I think the paper "On the generalized formulation of Debye shielding in plasmas" by G. Livadiotis should answer your question.

You can also refer to the paper written by the same author, "Electrostatic shielding in plasmas and the physical meaning of the Debye length."

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-plasma-physics/article/electrostatic-shielding-in-plasmas-and-the-physical-meaning-of-the-debye-length/60AD06F6C9547517458C52A6F191B161/share/80881b9deecf0be493680175bad02e5a3dae3155